How to make i3 aware of altered PATH configuration set in .bashrc
I installed pgadmin4 on my ubuntu with sudo apt-get pgadmin4. Apparently this makes the pgadmin binary end up in a directory that is not in PATH for some reason, namely in /usr/pgadmin4/bin. Therefore I added it to PATH in my .bashrc:
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/pgadmin4/bin"

Now when I restart my terminal I can invoke pgadmin4 from the cli with just pgadmin4 and it will find the binary.
But when I try to run the application from i3's executor dmenu (mod+d by default), pgadmin4 doesn't show up in the suggestions. I assume this is because i3 is not aware of the altered PATH configuration that I did in .bashrc. How can I make i3 aware of it?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Don't put PATH definitions in .bashrc. They don't belong there, and this is also why your i3 isn't seeing it, most likely, since .bashrc is only read by interactive shells.
So if you add the same line:
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/pgadmin4/bin"

To ~/.profile that should most likely work.
